# In R producing matrix of vectors and search for the optimum

Tags: r, data-structures, for-loop, mathematical-optimization

An elementary question: I apologize for it.
In R I would like to produce a data structure `x` with 2 indices, let us say `i` and `j`, s.t. (pseudocode)

```
for (i in 1:10){
  for (j in 1:20){
    x[i,j] <- c(i+j,j-i^2)
  }
}
```

i.e. each element of `x` is a vector with 2-components. Moreover, I would like to search in `x`
to find which pair `i,j` gives the maximum value of `j-i^2`; this should be accomplished in the above double `for`. Could you please give me some hints? I thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with `outer`. It is not clear from your question whether you are considering `i` and `j` as absolute values or as some sort of index vector. I am assuming that they are indices of a vector, `x`:

```
set.seed(1) 
x <- runif(20) 
matm <- outer( x[1:20] , (x[1:10])^2 , `-` )
matp <- outer( x[1:10] , x[1:20] , `+` )

head( cbind( i_plus_j = c(matm) , j_minus_i_sq = c(matp) ) )
#      i_plus_j j_minus_i_sq
#[1,] 0.1950138    0.5310173
#[2,] 0.3016290    0.6376326
#[3,] 0.5023585    0.8383620
#[4,] 0.8377129    1.1737165
#[5,] 0.1311871    0.4671906
#[6,] 0.8278948    1.1638983


which( matm == max( matm ) , arr.ind = TRUE  )
#     row col
#[1,]  18  10
```

Comment: thanks for your question; however, `i` and `j` are indices that identify the elements of `x`, and I need both of them. I would avoid, for example, to consider `x` as a list, because I do not want to consider a single index. Is it possible to define a list with double index, something like `x[[i,j]]`?

Comment: so change it to `outer( x[1:20] , (x[1:10])^2 , "-" )` and `outer( x[1:10] , x[1:20] , "+")`.

Comment: @Avitus you are welcome and i upated the question to reflect this. Cheers,